# Gerando Codigo de Barras (boleto bancario) com Angular

Tags: angular

Tenho uma aplicação rodando em angular 5(utilizando angular cli), estou realizando integração com um meio de pagamento, já tenho todos os dados necessário para gerar o boleto, ai que a dor de cabeça começou, gerar o código de barras.
Tentei utilizar algumas lib JS, como o boleto.js ou o boleto br, mas não tive muito exito, o padrão do febracan é intercalado 2 e 5, tentei pesquisar algum padrão exterior equivalente mas também não tive muito sucesso. Alguém tem alguma dica ?

Answer (score 3):

Pode dar uma olhada no pacote que existe para o angular 1.5 e adaptá-lo para o angular 5: https://github.com/allansli/angular-barcode-febraban#readme

Utilizar a fonte:
https://github.com/allansli/angular-barcode-febraban/blob/master/assets/fonts/BarcodeInterleaved2of5.ttf

**Criar uma classe para a fonte**:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "BarcodeInterleaved2of5";
    src: url("../fonts/BarcodeInterleaved2of5.ttf") format("truetype");
}

.barcodei2of5 {
     font-family: "BarcodeInterleaved2of5";
     font-size: 200px;
}
```

**Utilizar a função que gera a sequência interpretada pela fonte**:

```
 function generateBarcodeSequence(barcode) {
        var barcodeSequence = "";

        if (barcode.length > 0 &&
            barcode.length % 2 === 0) {
            for (var index = 0; index < barcode.length; index = index + 2) {

                var item = Number(barcode.substr(index, 2));
                var charCode;

                if (item <= 49) {
                    charCode = item + 48;
                }
                else {
                    charCode = item + 142;
                }

                barcodeSequence = barcodeSequence + String.fromCharCode(charCode);
            }

            barcodeSequence = "(" + barcodeSequence + ")";
        }

        return barcodeSequence;
    }
```

Por fim você encapsula em um componente de Angular 5 e utiliza em suas telas.

Answer (score 0):

Vai uma dica bem simples...

Utilize uma fonte de código de barras, **3 of 9 barcode** é um exemplo

para utilizar essa fonte é só colocar asterisco antes do primeiro número e asterisco depois do último.